# How can I show base currency price & display currency price at the same time in magento2?

Tags: price, currency, multicurrency

I would like to show product price in both base currency & display currency.

I have already enable display currency in frontend - that is i can see "USD / YEN" in header dropdown menu.

For display price with format price, i used this code to handle:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
$priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); // Instance of Pricing Helper
$price =  1000; //Your Price
$formattedPrice = $priceHelper->currency($price, true, false);
```

If i want to show 2 price, one in base currency, one in display currency at the same time, what should be the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally find out the code to show both display currency & base currency.

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
         $priceCurrencyObject = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface');
         $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
         $store = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
         $base = "USD";
         $rate = $priceCurrencyObject->convert($block->getDisplayValue(), $store, $base);
         $amount = $block->getDisplayValue();

         //If you want it in base currency then use:
         $current_currency = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();
         if ($current_currency!=$base) {
             $rate = $helper->priceCurrency->convert($amount, $store) / $amount;
             $amount = $amount / $rate;
             echo " (";
             echo $helper->priceCurrency->getCurrencySymbol(false, $base);
             echo $priceCurrencyObject->round($amount);
             echo ")";

         }
```